# How to convert rows into columns based on the specific row value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a output from select as below

```
| s.no | user_id | user_type | user_group | prefix | fname | mname | lname | suffix |nick_name | company | department | designation_title | industry | dob        | nationality | passport_number | photograph | mobile | email | permanent_address | temporary_address | bbm_p |t_number_arrival | departure_date_time | depart_airlines | flight_number_departure |

|   17 |       0 | Husband   |         23 | sasas  | asd   |       |       |       |           |          |            |                   |          |0000-00-00  |             |                 |            |      0 | asdas |                   | sadx              | asd| 0000-00-00 00:00:00   |                 |                         |
|   18 |       0 | wife      |         23 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   19 |       0 | kid1      |         23 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   20 |       0 | kid2      |         23 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   21 |       0 | kid3      |         23 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   22 |       0 | kid4      |         23 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   23 |       0 | Husband   |         24 | sasas  | asd   |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 | asdas |                   | sadx              | asd| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   24 |       0 | wife      |         24 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                 |                         |
|   25 |       0 | kid1      |         24 |        |       |       |       |        |           |         |            |                   |          | 0000-00-00 |             |                 |            |      0 |       |                   |                   |
```

Which I need to be converted as below

```
 | husband | wife | kid1 | kid2 | kid3 | kid4

   sasas  |       |      |       |      |
    asd   |       |      |       |      |
```

How can I modify my select query to group the records under 
husband , wife , kid1 , kid2 , kid 3 and kid 4 ?

Comment: what is your query you want to modify ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you be more specific?

Comment: u dont need kid3 and kid4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear but it seems like you want to *unpivot* the existing columns and then *pivot* the values in the `user_type` column.

If that is the case, then you will want to use a `UNION ALL` to unpivot the data and then apply an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to pivot to get the final result:

```
select user_id, 
  user_group,
  col_name,
  max(case when user_type = 'Husband' then value end) as Husband,
  max(case when user_type = 'wife' then value end) as Wife,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid1' then value end) as Kid1,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid2' then value end) as Kid2,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid3' then value end) as Kid3,
  max(case when user_type = 'ki4=d4' then value end) as Kid4
from
(
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'prefix' as col_name, prefix as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'fname' as col_name, fname as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'mname' as col_name, mname as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'lname' as col_name, lname as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'suffix' as col_name, suffix as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'nick_name' as col_name, nick_name as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'company' as col_name, company as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'department' as col_name, department as value
  from yourtable
) src
group by user_id, user_group, col_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08b5a/6). Your sample data does not have many values, but the result will be similar to this:

```
| USER_ID | USER_GROUP |   COL_NAME | HUSBAND |   WIFE |   KID1 |   KID2 |   KID3 |   KID4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       0 |         23 |    company |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 | department |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |      fname |     asd | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |      lname |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |      mname |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |  nick_name |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |     prefix |   sasas | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         23 |     suffix |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |    company |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 | department |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |      fname |     asd | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |      lname |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |      mname |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |  nick_name |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |     prefix |   sasas | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       0 |         24 |     suffix |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

*Note: I included additional columns to unpivot but if you only want the `fname` you would only include those columns in the subquery*

Edit #1, if you need to keep the order of the data based on the columns in the original table, then you can add a column to the `UNION ALL` queries with the sort order. You can then use that column in an `ORDER BY`. So the query will be:

```
select user_id, 
  user_group,
  col_name,
  max(case when user_type = 'Husband' then value end) as Husband,
  max(case when user_type = 'wife' then value end) as Wife,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid1' then value end) as Kid1,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid2' then value end) as Kid2,
  max(case when user_type = 'kid3' then value end) as Kid3,
  max(case when user_type = 'ki4=d4' then value end) as Kid4
from
(
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'prefix' as col_name, prefix as value
      , 1 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'fname' as col_name, fname as value
      , 2 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'mname' as col_name, mname as value
      , 3 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'lname' as col_name, lname as value
      , 4 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'suffix' as col_name, suffix as value
      , 5 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'nick_name' as col_name, nick_name as value
      , 6 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'company' as col_name, company as value
      , 7 as sortorder
  from yourtable
  union all
  select user_id, user_type, user_group,
      'department' as col_name, department as value
      , 8 as sortorder
  from yourtable
) src
group by user_id, user_group, col_name
order by user_group, sortorder
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08b5a/18)

Comment: Thanks but the query is ordering the col_NAME in alphabetical order , Can u please help me in skipping this ordering.

Comment: @oldrock I don't have an `order by` on the query. What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: the column name should be ordered as it was present in the table suppose prefix is first then col_NAME should start with prefix followed by fname , mname , lname  , suffix  , nick_name,company  .. etc

Comment: @oldrock all you need to do is add a column to the `UNION ALL` that will determine the sort order see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08b5a/18